# Nonhomogeneous linear systems with constant coefficients

Tags: calculus, differential

Consider the nonhomogeneous system for $\mathbf{x}(t)$:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} =
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{x} + \left[\begin{array}{c}
t\\
\sin t
\end{array}\right] .
$$
The goal is to find the general solution for the non homogeneous linear system.

I've found general solution of the corresponding homogeneous system (although unsure) but it was
$$
\mathbf{x}_h = c_1 e^{-t} \left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2
\end{array}\right] + c_2 t e^{-t} \left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2
\end{array}\right]
$$
because my eigenvalue was $-1$ and the eigenvector I got was $[1,2]^\top$.

I'm onto finding particular solution which I guessed (could be wrong) to be in the form:
$$
\mathbf{x}_p = a \cos(t) + b \sin(t) + c 
$$
and 
\begin{aligned}
&LHS= \mathbf{x}_p' = -a \sin(t) + b \cos (t) \\
&RHS = A \mathbf{x}_p+ g = A a \cos(t) + A b \sin(t) + Ac + \left[\begin{array}{c}
t\\
\sin t
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}

Now I'm finding trouble matching the coefficients as I can't separate the $t $ out of my $g(t)$ which was $[t, \sin(t)]^\top$.

I'm stuck there. Thanks.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial, it could be useful](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: To solve ODE systems of the type $\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}(t) + \mathbf{B}(t)$, follow the steps in the first paragraph of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349648/a-question-about-finite-element-method/2349709#2349709).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the nonhomogeneous part, but that matrix should have two distinct, real eigenvalues, not just one, namely $1$ and $-1$. Further, the eigenvectors should be 
$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$ 
and 
$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
-2
\end{matrix}
\right]
$
, respectively, of course allowing for multiplication by an arbitrary constant. So perhaps double check your homogeneous solution.